# Difference in the implied meaning when different words for “Shining” used?

Tags: differences

Please consider the sentences below:

> The grass was **glittering** with dew.
>   The grass was **glistening** with dew.
>   The grass was **glinting** with dew.
>   The grass was **gleaming** with dew.

Below are the definitions given by my dictionary.

> **Glisten** = (of something wet or greasy) shine with a sparkling light.
>   **Glitter** = shine with a bright, shimmering reflected light.
>   **Glint** = give out or reflect small flashes of light.
>   **Gleam** = shine brightly, especially with reflected light.

I know that even if two words are synonyms, they can imply different meanings, even when the dictionary definitions look almost identical (as they do here). Are there any such differences between the *implied* meanings of the example sentences above?

Comment: How could you have left out ***glistering*** and ***glowing*** — not to mention *shining, sparkling, twinkling, spangling, scintillating*, and *coruscating*?

Comment: Like it or not, these types of questions are specifically ***ALLOWED*** on this site. Please, please, please, stop closing them. (And the fact that there are other near-synonyms that the OP could have listed is totally irrelevant. She didn't ask about those because *she doesn't need to know about them*.)

Comment: I feel like this is a definite case of "a picture is worth a thousand words", but I have neither the time nor the expertise to create such pictures. :/

Comment: @Marthaª: I don't completely agree that other near-synonyms are irrelevant. In a question like this, I'm usually left wondering, "Why these four words, and not others?" In other words, I think the O.P. could further improve such questions if some hint of context or purpose was provided. (That all said, I'm sticking with your exhortation, and not voting negatively, but opting to post pictures instead.)

Comment: There is a concept called semantic trait that comes into play here. Often, native speakers masters these unconsciously. Then, there is the issue of Latin versus Greek origin for what are basicially synonyms. And I am sorry but don't feel like applying my brain power to this. It would take pages and pages.  One example: glinting is usually about a hard surface, ergo, I would not use it here to describe the relationship with how the dew looked on the grass. So, if grass is glinting with dew, the writer is viewing the grass as  a hard surface...

Answer (score 6):

There's not much of a difference between any of the words in that sentence, and indeed they are all very similar in general.  If I were to assign shades of meaning to them, I'd probably break it down like this, more or less in decreasing order of brightness/eye-catchingness:

**Glitter:** a bright, shiny sparkle that twinkles rapidly.

**Glisten:** a soft, less-pronounced sparkle with occasional twinkles.

**Gleam:** a continuous soft shine with occasional twinkles of additional brightness.

**Glint:** a single twinkle or sparkle.

In regard to your example sentence, I'd say "glittered" is probably the most fitting since there is a lot of grass and a lot of individual dew drops, each of which can catch the light and cause a twinkle, so the overall effect would be a lot of small, rapid twinkles.

Comment: I tend to think that hard shiny objects glitter.  Things that are wet glisten.

Comment: Yes, I agree that there is a continuous de-/con-notation with 'gleam'.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer your second sentence.  Simply change the word "glistening" to "glistened":

> The grass glistened with dew.

Answer (score 2):

I like the first two words (*glistening* & *glittering*), as well as tchrist's *shining*.

*Glittering* might be especially apt if the dew was causing several individual points of light, as if [glitter](http://www.coloronpro.com/products/large/metallic-silver-glitter1.jpg) had been spread across the lawn.

I'm not so fond of *glinting*, perhaps because I often associate it with someone's eyes.  NOAD lists this definition:

> • (of a person's eyes) shine with a particular emotion : *his eyes glinted angrily*.

That said, the word's primary meaning is "give out or reflect small flashes of light," so it *could* be used in the dewy grass sentence.

Similarly, there's nothing wrong with *gleam* per se, but NOAD lists these definitions:

> • (of a smooth surface or object) reflect light because well polished : *Victor buffed the glass until it gleamed* | [as adj] (gleaming) *sleek and gleaming black limousines*.
>   • (of an emotion or quality) appear or be expressed through the brightness of someone's eyes or expression : a hint of mischief gleaming in her eyes.

Since grass is not well-polished, and there are also more ties to eyes and emotions, I'd steer away from *gleam* as well.

As a general rule, it's worth examining secondary and tertiary definitions of words when trying to learn about how synonyms differ. Those additional meanings will sometimes – though not always – hold the keys to understanding why some words may sound a bit more out of place than others in certain contexts.

As for Martha's comments about pictures being worth a thousand words, that's another technique you can use. For example, I found these pictures using the Google image search:

[image: gleaming grass] [image: glinting grass]
[image: glistening grass] [image: glittering grass]

I found these four images by typing (from top to bottom): "gleaming grass", "glinting grass", "glistening grass", and "glittering grass" into the Google image search bar. As you can see, the terms are largely interchangeable in this context.  In fact, one of the pictures was captioned *"magical atmosphere of the glittering and gleaming carpet in the grass,"* as if one adjective wasn't entirely sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Things that glitter, glisten and glint are usually reflecting light from another source - but this is by no means always the case, stars being a counter-example. Things that gleam are often radiating light in their own right i.e. similar in some ways to glowing (but "cooler"?)