# What is the word for the reflected sun light?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, dictionaries

I can't remember what is the word for those funny light spots created when you take a mirror or any reflecting surface and make a spot of light that can be moved all over the room, walls, etc. Does anyone know?

Comment: Maybe "glint"? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glint

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/127189 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/159198 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95334 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/185891 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/267113 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/178809 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/294429 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/316995 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/299720 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/127266 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/127145 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/192609 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/227855 et cetera.

Comment: @tchrist I'm impressed that you found 13 potential duplicates before deciding to add "et cetera".

Comment: There is a word in South American Spanish for this phenomena as well and I cannot for the life of me remember it right now, but I remember when I learned about it wishing there was an English equivalent.

Comment: In my native language, we colloquially call them "sun bunnies" - because you can use a mirror to make them jump around like bunnies. I came here trying to find out how to translate "sun bunnies" to English. So, there is no similar poethic term in English, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

In my family (rural Australia) we have always used the term "jack-a-dandy". I can trace this back to a usage in 19th C London (sorry, reference escapes me - not my family, though.) It was an article on children's games. One boy complained that another had cast a jack-a-dandy in his eye with a mirror or similar. The trail stops there. I tracked down an earlier (?) English saying to the effect that, on a day when sun and rain alternated rapidly, "Jack-a-dandy is beating his wife with his golden stick". In Germany, in the same circumstances, it is the devil who is beating his wife. My Jamaican sister-in-law reports a similar saying in Jamaica.

Reference added:

*Jack-a-dandy* -- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jack-a-dandy)

> (noun) 2. (New Zealand) A small patch of light reflected from a shiny surface onto another surface such as a wall or ceiling.

Answer (score 2):

My Dad used to say "icky more, icky more, shinning on the kitchen door". I assumed everyone use to say that, but I now realise that everyone has their own names for them.

Answer (score 2):

The specific optical effect you are after is:

[Caustics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_(optics))

> In optics, a caustic is the envelope of light rays reflected or refracted by a curved surface or object, or the **projection of that envelope of rays on another surface.**

---

Note, that even very slightly curved surfaces such as a the glass on a watch can (and do) cause caustic reflections.

Answer (score -1):

Reflections:

> ***the act of reflecting, as in casting back a light*** or heat, mirroring, or giving back or showing an image; the state of being reflected in this way.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: Wow, great, thanks for the answers! We have a phrase for this is Bulgarian 'sun bunny' and I couldn't escape the feeling that there is something similar in English. Obviously there is not :) Thanks!

Comment: @Theo Not common in English, but in my family we called the singular reflection cast by sunlight bouncing off my father's wristwatch onto the car's interior during long boring car rides "the peanut" (due to the oblong shape created by a circular reflection hitting a surface at an angle). He used to move it around and create stories about it to amuse us and ameliorate the boredom.