# Is There a Word for the Spot on the Floor at the end of a Sunbeam?

Tags: meaning

When the Sun or the Moon shines through a window, there's a corresponding bright spot on the floor or wall. Conversely, when an object blocks light, it casts a shadow. What would the term be for this opposite?

**EDIT**: I'm searching for a word that describes the bright spot, not the shadow.

Maybe some context will help.

I have this large picture window in my living room that, on the night of a full Moon, produces this stunning effect after Moonrise. When describing it, I find myself saying:

> "If you turn out the lights, the moonlight entering the window casts an eerily beautiful {{word}} on the opposite wall."

Best I've come up with so far is **sheen**.

Comment: A spot that is [lit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lit)?

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/127189 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/159198 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95334 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/185891 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/267113 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/178809 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/294429 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/316995 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/299720 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/127266 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/127145 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/192609 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/227855 et cetera.

Comment: "The Spot on the Floor at the End of a Rainbow is called the Crock of Gold".

Comment: @PeterPoint I discovered in my youth that some blighter has stolen it.

Comment: @Mick I feel a song coming coming on... Somewhere over the rainbow, way up high; There's a land that I've heard of once in a lullaby; Somewhere over the rainbow, skies are blue; And you'll find my old chum Kayzer, counting out his... ill gotten gains. ...........He's the blighter who filched the crock, don't ya know? Apologies to Judy Garland and anyone else out there reading this tomfoolery.

Comment: @PeterPoint What? Crock of gold? I'd opt for pot every time! What?

Comment: Re the question. Is about the light or the shadow? I can't tell. The question seems to be about the former, the question body about the latter. Please clarify before my friend @PeterPoint spews out another song or provocative quote of some sort.

Comment: @RichardKayser Quite so, Rich. Quite so!

Comment: @PeterPoint You're fun.

Comment: A pool of light?

Comment: @RichardKayser - see my edit. I'm asking about the light.

Comment: Are you saying that there's a specific spot of light which looks like a picture of the moon? That's not how sunlight and moonlight normally appear, something must be focussing it. Do you have a piece of feature glass in the window, a glass pendant hanging in the window or some sort of hole somewhere which could act as a pinhole camera? If that's the case you would call the spot an **image** of the moon.

Comment: @BoldBen: I think he's saying it's just the outline of the window, making a very clear, crisp patch of light on the opposite wall.

Comment: Shadow is just another word for darkness. The opposite of a shadow would be a ray or beam of light. Technically there's not a word for "the spot on the floor where a shadow falls" so I wouldn't expect there to be an antonym.

Comment: @tchrist None of those had anything to do with this question.

Comment: I would generally call the spot a *sunbeam* or *moonbeam*.  When people use those terms they are quite often referring to the "spot" produced, vs the (invisible) beam of light moving through the atmosphere.

Comment: Spotlight. That's me in the Spotlight, loosing my religion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a great amount of digging for this, but I think we all might agree that there might not be a word to uniquely describe this phenomenon.  I went through a large amount of solar and planetary terminology to make certain there wasn't anything I was missing.

While "sheen" is probably acceptable, I would offer up the alternative of "glow".

> The moonlight through the window cast an eerie glow onto the wall.

Answer (score 3):

**Dapple**: a patch or spot of color or light.

It's usually used in a context where there are many such patches ("The sun-dappled forest floor"), so it's not a perfect fit but it does describe a patch of light.

Answer (score 0):

Both [theater terminology](http://www.theatrecrafts.com/pages/home/topics/lighting/glossary-beginners/) and [physics jargon](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=43411) seem to agree that beams of light create [hot spots](http://www.iar.unicamp.br/lab/luz/ld/C%EAnica/Gloss%E1rios/glossary_of_stage_terms.pdf).

- Tonight we shall not require a lamp for our play, as the moon is providing a natural **hot spot**.

[image: Hot Spot, the musical]

Answer (score 0):

I have used the term "sun puddle" for sunbeams on floors.

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sun%20puddle) has this definition with about 15 upvotes, so its not just me.

I have no word for a "moon puddle" though. "Moon pool" feels right, but that's already taken to mean something else.

I have no word for either light source on a wall.